# Stopping a recursive function in Python

Tags: python

The program should od as follows: Find out if two people are connected (directly or indirectly) and list out the path over which the two people are connected, using recursion.
The problem occurs in the line *return True*, as the recursion doesn't break and just continues as if the if statement was not true.

```
def trace(info, first, second):
    for a, b in info:
        if a == first:
            print(a, b)
            if b == second:
                return True
            else:
                trace(info, b, second)
    return False
    


info = [('zayn', 'anna'), ('jake', 'maria'), ('pete', 'anna'), ('travis', 'hannah'), ('maria', 'sara'), ('anna', 'mark'), ('sara', 'zayn'), ('sara', 'pete'), ('sara', 'mark')]

trace(info, 'jake', 'mark')
```

Comment: I think you've missed out a line of code

Comment: You are missing the return statement from the recursive call `else: return trance(info, b, second)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement from the recursive call:

```py
def trace(info, first, second):
    for a, b in info:
        if a == first:
            print(a, b)
            if b == second:
                return True
            else:
                return trace(info, b, second)
    return False
```

[Playground](https://www.online-python.com/jRlQ1XnObG)